# AWS CLI -- adding a new security group to instances without deleting old security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-security-group

So I have written this script, which extracts all EC2 instances associated with a given security group (sgexisting) , and then it adds a new (sgnew) security group to those EC2 instances.

My only issue is that `aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $name --groups $2` cannot simply append a new security group to an instance. The new security group will overwrite all existing security groups. If you want to add a new security group to an instance, you must list the new security group and all of the existing security groups that were attached to that instance.

Is there an aws cli command to simply add a new security group to instance without over-writing/deleting all of the existing security group? or can anyone suggest a simple work around?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sgexisting =$1

sgnew =$2 

function test () {


  aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PublicIP:PublicIpAddress,Type:InstanceType,InstanceId:InstanceId,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Status:State.Name,SecurityGroups:SecurityGroups[*]}" \
  --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=instance-type,Values='t2.medium','t2.micro'" "Name=instance.group-name,Values="$1"" \
  --output json

} 


test "$sgname" > /home/sosa/extracted1.json

as=$(cat /home/sosa/extracted1.json | awk '/"InstanceId"/ {print $2}' | tr -d \"\,) 
echo "$as" >> /home/sosa/extracted4.json 


while read name; do

  aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $name --groups $2 

  aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id $name --attribute groupSet

done <"/home/sosa/extracted4.json"
```

Comment: You get existing SGs and append new ones to the result. And then perform the instance update.

Comment: Marcin comment is the way to do because command expects to write the original command and then new ones, so if you want to avoid writing the existing ones, you need to store existing security group in array , append new ones and then specify it in the command